# What are the differences between comment_form_logged_in_after and comment_form_after_fields?

Tags: hooks

**This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/348492/109240).**

When hooking into the add comment form there are two hooks to use:

1. comment_form_logged_in_after
2. comment_form_after_fields

Am I right in assuming that the first is for logged in users and the second for anon users? Are there any other differences I should be aware of?

For the benefit of anyone coming here via a search engine, please explain as if I am a slow learner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I right in assuming that the first is for logged in users and the
>   second for anon users?

Yes.

And "a picture is worth a thousand words"; so, see and compare the sample output/previews below. (The theme used is the Twenty Nineteen theme.)

### 1. `comment_form_logged_in_after`

- WordPress runs this hook if the current user is logged-in.
- You can use this hook to add something after the *opening `<form>` tag* — or more precisely, after whatever stuff added via the `comment_form_top` hook — and that something would be displayed before the comment field (which is the text box/`textarea` for entering the comment text/content).
- This hook is basically a shortcut to using the `comment_form_top` hook with `is_user_logged_in()`:

  ```php
  // Note that WordPress runs comment_form_top regardless the user is logged-in or not.
  add_action( 'comment_form_top', function () {
      if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
          echo 'comment_form_top: is logged-in<br />';
      } else {
          echo 'comment_form_top: not logged-in<br />';
      }
  } );
  ```

[image]

### 2. `comment_form_after_fields`

- WordPress runs this hook if the current user is *not* logged-in.
- You can use this hook to add something in *between the last field and the submit button* in the form — in the preview below, the last field is the one below the "Save my name, email, ..." (i.e. cookies consent).
- This hook is similar to `comment_form_before_fields` which you can use to add something in *between the comment field and the name field* in the form.

So referring to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/348506), the `add_my_custom_field_to_comment_form` function is hooked to both `comment_form_logged_in_after` and `comment_form_after_fields` so that the custom field would appear for both authenticated and non-authenticated users.

Why so: When the user is not authenticated, extra form fields are displayed after the comment field. When the user is authenticated, then the extra form fields are not displayed by default. (Extra form fields are those other than the comment field; see [`$fields`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comment_form/#parameters).)

[image]

*(Note that this answer covers the default behaviors in WordPress. Plugins and themes may change **any** of the behaviors, such as using CSS/JavaScript to change element's position/visibility/etc.)*

And for all the currently available hooks for the comment form (i.e. `comment_form()`), check [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/files/wp-includes/comment-template.php/?post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-hook).